# How can I override the exisiting Schema.org markup from Yoast using GTM?

Tags: wordpress, seo, schema.org, yoast

I've configured my GTM with the JSON-LD markup I placed in GTM and its firing perfectly. However, if I will check it in [structured data testing tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/?authuser=0) still the auto-generated markup by Yoast is showing.

[image: screenshot of my markup by yoast]

Can I just remove or disable the Yoast schema? Will it not be harmful in terms of SEO?

Comment: Please note that asking for SEO advice ("Will it not be harmful in terms of SEO?") is off-topic on Stack Overflow. You can [edit] your question to remove the SEO question. Or you could ask this on [webmasters.se], where SEO advice is on-topic.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the first question, you can remove all the Yoast schema by adding the following to your functions.php (should be in your child theme):

```
  function bybe_remove_yoast_json($data){
    $data = array();
    return $data;
  }
  add_filter('wpseo_json_ld_output', 'bybe_remove_yoast_json', 10, 1);
```

Tested working and per: https://www.bybe.net/yoast-seo-guide-disable-schema-json-ld-wordpress/

Comment: can you help me how to to modify the schema of yoast plugin for breadcrumbs using php?

Answer (score 0):

There's no harm in what Yoast is adding. You could leave it there. Or you could devise some JavaScript to find the script tag and remove it.